# When was Lucy's mission first scripted in Excel and why is that what Lockheed Martin chose to do it with?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, mission-design, trajectory, calculation, lucy-asteroid-mission

CNBC's [NASA spacecraft launches toward Jupiter asteroids on an intricate path charted by Excel](https://www.cnbc.com/2021/10/18/lockheed-martin-nasa-spacecraft-lucy-heads-to-jupiter-asteroids-with-help-from-excel.html)

> Years before Lucy took off, Lockheed Martin mission architect Brian Sutter **used Excel to chart the mission’s path and choose which of the about 5,000 Trojan asteroids** the spacecraft should visit.
>
> “Part of the science of this mission was to try to look at as many of these Trojans as we can in a single mission,” Sutter told CNBC.
>
> While Lockheed Martin has a “high fidelity” tool to run individual trajectories, Sutter said that would have taken “forever.” He instead turned to an Excel macro, which is “perfectly suited for sorting through large quantities of data.”
>
> “I had already found a trajectory that connected two of the asteroids to a trajectory that also connected to Earth,” Sutter said.
>
> **Orbit propagation – or modeling the future location of objects in space – “is what I do,” Sutter explained. While his macro consists of “different equations than you’d normally put into Excel,” he emphasized that “at the end of the day it’s all math.”
>
> **Sutter took a broad list of 750,000 asteroids and entered them into Excel** to “see if they ever accidentally kind of come close to each other.”
>
> “I think this thing took about 12 hours to cycle through all 750,000 of them,” Sutter said. After he ran the macro, he had “a little list of 10 to 20 asteroids that the spacecraft was going to be flying close to.”
>
> His use of Excel to help chart Lucy’s trajectory became famous within Lockheed Martin. He recalled that a colleague once described to others that Sutter “built the most ridiculously complicated Excel spreadsheet I’ve ever seen in my life.”

Hmm...

I've used Excel for scientific numerical computing myself, but it was 20 years ago, and because I was in a pinch and had nothing else available. Now that python/numpy/scipy are so universal I can not imagine why someone would turn to scripting in Excel rather than scripting in Python.

Excel [can't even get Bessel functions to better than five digits](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/30279/17869) (not that you'd use Bessel functions to calculate trajectories; just sayin'...)

**Question:**

1. How long ago was this? When was Lucy's mission first scripted in Excel?
2. How many asteroid were considered; about 5,000 Trojans or "a broad list of 750,000"?

Comment: Both Excel and the standard Python implementation use IEEE 64-bit floating point math operations internally; if Excel’s Bessel function is broken that doesn’t speak to any inherent problem with Excel. 99% likely that Sutter was simply more familiar with Excel than Python, and for a one-off job that was just identifying candidates for further study, it got the job done.

Comment: @RussellBorogove propagating 750,000 asteroid orbits and calculating 750,000 x 750,000 inter-asteroid distances at each time step will challenge Excel beyond floating point issues. Clever scripting can reduce that problem size substantially of course, and *I agree 100%* that the tool to use is the tool you have in front of you. I think this is an interesting story with several interesting aspects, hopefully we can find out more.

Comment: This is not at all surprising. Many years ago, I took a shot at climbing the management ladder. In the process I became intimately familiar with Excel. I found that management was not my cup of tea; I would much rather be doing technical work. I intentionally found a way to get back onto the technical ladder. There are lots of managers who are intimately familiar with Excel. It often is their go-to tool. When they do get the rare chance to do technical work, they'll often do it in Excel. With the hours they work, they don't have the time to learn about python/numpy/scipy, whatever.

Comment: The last question, the one you appear to be most interested in, is completely separate from the other two. And the answer is simple: Internal Research & Development (or possibly Bid & Proposal). NASA did not pay Lockheed-Martin to come up with the design.

Comment: @DavidHammen okay sold! I'll split off "Why was the spacecraft builder also the mission architect?" as a separate question, will take some time to refactor it, perhaps generalize a bit. Perhaps something like "Did aerospace companies every pitch deep space science mission designs to NASA? If so, what are some notable examples?"

Comment: @uhoh This is just an educated guess, but I think Excel would take about 12 hours to cycle through all 750,000 of them.

Comment: @RussellBorogove It will be interesting to find out what Sutter actually did. If they really started with a single pre-planned trajectory and only looked for which other asteroids it happened to pass, then it's a length N calculation. But if they  "entered them into Excel to 'see if they ever accidentally kind of come close to each other'" that would be an $N^2$ calculation. I guess now that it's the former rather than the latter.

Comment: @RussellBorogove  One caveat, the computer used would now be about 10 years old as the [proposal submission deadline was in 2015](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_of_Discovery_Mission_13_and_14) and so one needs to check the speed on a 10 year old version of Excel.

Comment: @uhoh One of us didn’t read your question and at this point I’m honestly not sure which of us it is.

Comment: @RussellBorogove To me the statements in the block quote are somewhat self-contradictory in at least two ways. It mentions both N = 5,000 and 750,000 asteroids being examined, and it mentions both which asteroids appear near a given trajectory "the spacecraft was going to be flying close to" (length N calculation) and which "asteroids... come close to *each other*" (length N^2 calculation). It's certainly possible that what the article is trying to say is clear to everybody except me, that's been known to happen!

Comment: This is another example of an observation I made a long time ago - senior management of organizations are usually blissfully ignorant about software: it's capabilities & what could or should be used. Their concern is about a job being done by a deadline so the organization can make money. How the person does the job, what tools are used, as long as it doesn't cost the organization money, is up to the person doing the job.

Comment: @Fred Is getting the job done by a deadline in order to make money somehow a negative thing? I think it's great someone got an answer, and as mentioned I've even used massive spreadsheets as "Do loops" when I didn't have time to learn how to script them. So finding some asteroids is a happy ending to what sounds like a very interesting story, I'd just like to hear more about it.

Comment: Sometimes management can have tunnel vision & not realize that doing things smarter can sometimes be an opportunity to make even more money. As for spreadsheets, a friend of mine still uses a complex spreadsheet he initially started in the mid 1990s when he was using Lotus 123. I can still remember him complaining how he had to reestablish it in Excel over 20 years ago.